# ssh: Could not resolve hostname add: Name or service not known

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I created non-sudo user and I can't add ssh key while logined with it:

```
% ssh -vvv add ~/.ssh/mykey   
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname add: Name or service not known
```

Ubuntu 14.04, didn't change ssh config after clean installation.

When I add key while logined as sudo user everything is ok.
I tried to do

```
% eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 18372
```

But `ssh add` shows the same error after this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh -vvv add ~/.ssh/mykey` will try to connect to server `add` and run the `~/.ssh/mykey` command.

This is obviously not what you want but it certainly explains the error you're getting.

Comment: thanks, I must have used `ssh-add`, not `ssh add`. :)